# How/Where to store HTTP-Request URLs in Android?

Tags: android, httprequest, android-volley

I am not sure how/where I should store my Http-Request URLs and how to organize them.

I am developing a server and a client for Android. On the client I am using Volley for the network communication which so far seems like a very useful tool. The only thing I just don't know is the thing with all those Http-Request URLs.

Are there any best practices out there? Do I keep them all in a central class that provides all strings as a `static` field or do I store them as `private` field where I need them or is there another tool I can use for such things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen people generally doing the following things

1. Keeping URLs in a holder class with static fields
2. Keeping URLs in a resource XML file. This works exactly the same way
   as your strings.xml, but it is in a separate file. This comes in
   handy when using different server URLs in different app flavours
3. Keeping only the base server URL and then appending query params to
   it in separate files... request methods.

I use number two with conjunction with number three (keeping base URL in XML file and then appending stuff to the method)

Comment: I think I'll go for 2) and 3) but somehow I can't access the values from another `.xml` file. I have created a new resource file `http_request_urls.xml` and defined a value like `<string name="test">http://test</string>` but I can't access it. Any guess why?

Comment: my guess is that you are accessing it wrongly.. access it the same way you would access a string `R.string.url_name` ... you should also have SQL statments like this, it makes them much more readable... meaning less chance for a mistake

Comment: Hmm.. I did it like that but the `name` is just not found :/ If I were to implement SQL statements on the client I might do that as well - for now the server does all that :)

Comment: Try to rebuild your project, so that the XML file gets compiled. then use context.getString(R.string....)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a clean way to organise your request URLs consider using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), the library which is super useful in this sense. Here is an example of how it looks:

```
public interface WebService {  

    @POST("/mvc-api/membership/v1/accounts/login") LoginResponse login(@Body LoginRequestBody login);

    @POST("/mvc-api/membership/v1/accounts/registration") SignUpResponse(@Body SignUpRequestBody signUpBody);
}
```

Comment: That looks very nice indeed but I think I want to stick with Volley.